# MIstakenly changed file permissions in a working git repo

Tags: git, merge, push, branch

I had earlier pulled a branch from master and while working I mistakenly changed the file and directory permissions. Will those changes be reflected in master while merging even though the directory permission changes are not being showed in "git diff"?

edit: I'm working on a Linux machine.

Comment: I'm currently working on linux

Comment: I am surprised that `git diff` is not showing the changes in permissions ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388811/show-git-diff-ignoring-file-permission-changes)).  Perhaps your Git is configured to ignore permissions.

Comment: The change in the file permissions were shown by git diff but directory permissions weren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only file permissions Git does track is whether something is executable or not. If you haven’t made a change on the executable bit, then there will be no permission change in your commit and others will not be affected by it.

The file permissions will stay active within your local working directory though, so you should be aware of that. It is possible that certain actions (e.g. checking out a different branch) may or may not overwrite the file permissions on those files individually again in the check-out process.

Comment: Same thing there, Git does not track any file mode on directories.