# Ignore mode changes with git status

Tags: git, git-status

Is there a way to run `git status` while ignoring `mode` file changes?

Seems like there's a way to do it for git diff (`git diff -G.`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/22389011 but I can't seem to find a way to do this for `status`

Comment: Go up a bit from the answer you linked, to the accepted answer. Note that `git status` runs `git diff` (twice—once for `HEAD` vs index, then again for index vs work-tree) internally.

Answer (score 0):

This will ignore filemode for a single `git status` command and not change anything in the repo configuration:

```
git -c core.filemode=false status
```

Capitalization of the configuration parameter `core.filemode` is immaterial so this will also work:

```
git -c CORE.FileMode=false status
```

Note that the `-c` flag is passed to the `git` command, not the `status` subcommand, so this will not work:

```
$ git status -c core.filemode=false
error: unknown switch `c'
```

Running this command for the first time will probably require refreshing the index, which may take a while. If you don't want this repo to track filemode changes at all, you can do that as well:

```
git config core.filemode false
```

This will change the setting in `.git/config` of the current repo. If you want to apply this to all repos you interact with by changing the setting in `~/.gitconfig`, run this instead:

```
git config --global core.filemode false
```