# Git diff ignore mode

Tags: git, diff

I want to ignore mode changes for `git diff`.

I've tried `core.filemode` but it doesn't work.

```
$ touch foo bar
$ git -c core.filemode=false diff --no-index foo bar
diff --git a/foo b/bar
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

How can I have `git diff` ignore mode changes?

Comment: @matt, no it seems like it should but as I demonstrate, `core.filemode` doesn't work.

Comment: Howzabout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388811/show-git-diff-ignoring-file-permission-changes

Comment: The `core.filemode` problem is limited to `--no-index` diffs, and there is a workaround.